# Ugly css input issue

Tags: css

If you go [here](http://taraontv.com/contact.html), let the input fields empty and press Submit, you will notice that Name input is over the "The field is required" popup.

I have tried to apply z-index and other css strange "solutions" but I am simply unable to fix that...

Can you please suggest something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing....

```
formError {
position: absolute;
top: 300px;
left: 300px;
display: block;
z-index: 5000;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

to:

```
formError {
position: absolute;
top: 300px;
left: 300px;
display: block;
z-index: 9999;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

in the `validationEngine.jquery.css` file

**EDIT:** Also you might want to change

```
#contentContainer .content{ position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:680px; z-index:999999; margin-bottom:20px;}
```

To a z-index that's more reasonable.

Comment: See edit above. You've got the content set to be above anything else.

Comment: Thanks, here was the key indeed!

Answer (score 0):

```
.emailformError {
z-index: 999999;
}
```

Will do it :)

(All I have done is brought the bubble higher in the z-index (brought it above the other layers).)